# Need help trying understanding how to configure DNS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, routing

Our domain is hosted at rackspace and we use there DNS manager for managing DNS entries to all of our public servers.

We have entries for things like WebServer.MyDomain.com, AppServer.MyDomain.com, etc. All those machines have public static IP addresses.

We have a number of machines at our main office that we need access to remotely that are behind a firewall and we only have 1 static IP address.

I want to setup dns entries on a server at the office so that MyPC.MyDomain.com will get routed to my desktop pc behind the firewall.

I'm running Windows Server 2008 and have DNS installed. Here's what I think I need to do:

1. Setup an alias on rackspace that
   points MyPC.MyDomain.com to the
   server at the office.
2. On the office server setup dns and
   create a new Forward Lookup Zone
   MyDomain.com
3. Create a new A record in the new
   zone on the office server that
   points MyPc.MyDomain.com to the
   internal IP address.
4. Setup the router to point to the new internal dns server

Is this correct? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Set up an A record at Rackspace for MyPC.MyDomain.com that points to the 1 static IP address (of your office's Internet router).

Configure the router to allow port-forwarding of port 80 (for example) to port 80 at the internal IP-address of the desktop PC.

For other PCs you would port-forward say port 81 to port 80 of the internal IP-address of a second PC, and so on.

Since you only have 1 public IP-address you have to use port-forwarding.

Note that this opens those PCs to attacks on that port - any exposed services will come under attack sooner or later - probably sooner.

If VPN or some other service would meet your needs, you should consider that instead.

Comment: I have to use port forwarding? There's no way to setup an additional dns entry so when the request comes in it gets mapped to an internal ip?

Comment: It depends on the protocol to some extent. At the IP-layer, the packet addresses are based only on IP-addresses and Port-numbers, not on DNS hostnames. Your router operates at the IP-layer. Check your router manual but don't hold your breath.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you need even a dns server at office to handle this ,
just create A record of your valid ip to office linke office.yourdomain.com
then forward your desired port on office server to your local machine, this will be done by destnat from one port to another.
for example, to forward RDP port of your machine : 
destnat from VALIDIP:33891 ~> LOCALIP:3389
thats all you need to do!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is this:

1. Set up an **A** record on the DNS server for your domain that point to the *public* IP address(i think is rackspace thats hosting your DNS) of your Firewall
   **i.e.** *MyPC.MyDomain.com -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx*
2. Set up a Port forwarding on the Router/Firewall that has the Public IP address configured to forward the port of the service you want to the internal IP address of your server/Desktop you could find how to do port forwarding in this site> http://portforward.com/
3. .....
4. Profit?